# Is exposing IP address secure?

Tags: security, ip, api-design

I'm behind a company firewall and have been asked to share my IP address in order for me to be white-listed so can access an API. This is first time I've been asked for this and find it uncommon ? as usually I connect to an API via OAuth or access token, https username password etc. Is this a safe way to access an API, will I creating any security risks though sharing my IP ?

Update : 
The API host is asking for my IP.

Comment: who's asking for the IP? your company, or the API host?

Comment: @MarcB the API host.

Comment: then you'd first have to check what your corporate firewall is doing. if it's a NAT system, then your internal ip is irrelevant. the API would only see the external gateway/router IP.

Comment: @MarcB So the ip returned by Googling 'whats my ip google' is irrelevant if behind a NAT system ?

Comment: no, that'd be the one you have to give the API, because that's what it'll be seeing as well. But if you give your internal ip (e.g. open up a command promp and do `ifconfig`/`ipconfig`, that's the irrelevant IP - that's probably a private 10.x.x.x, 192.168.x.x., etc... IP and will never be visible to the internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You give your (external) IP address to every single website you visit. It's ok to let them strengthen access control by IP restriction.

However, if that is the *only* security measure (as opposed to proper authentication and access control), that's not OK, especially not in a corporate setting, where everybody behind your firewall will have the same external IP address because of NAT (and even if it's not the case, there must be proper authentication on a secure API).